# Saving Oscilloscope Traces as Compressed Bitstream

Tags: oscilloscope, comparator, output, recording

I have been recording the output of a comparator by having its output (essentially a bit stream with 3.3V swing @ ~20 Mbps) terminating in an SMA connector, and connecting that to an oscilloscope (which is used to record the traces). This is fine for short periods like 0.1s, but becomes unpractical for larger time periods as the traces require to much hard disk space to record (~1 GB/s) because of the required oscilloscope resolution to differentiate between the bits in the comparator output bit stream.

What I'm looking for is either some sort of DAQ device that takes output of the comparator, and saves it as a stream of 0's and 1's and compresses it, or a circuit that could be designed to carry out this task.

How do I save the output of a DAQ device and compress the bitstream?

Comment: A logic analyzer?

Comment: How much amplitude resolution do you require?  The mention of a comparator makes it sound like only one bit.  So bit packing would be an improvement, but many logic analyzer can save data in a format which instead time- or samplecount- stamps each change.

Comment: You're talking about differentiating between bits...is this a serial data stream of some sort?

Comment: Why not just send time stamps for the transition (or value and transition if you're worried about errors)

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the ratio between the average period and the frequency of state changes, some form of run-length encoding may be the most effective approach.  That would be especially true if the only things of interest are long runs of high, long runs of low, or periods that can't be characterized as other [e.g.
if the shortest runs of interest are length 4, then something like

```
 111111110010100010000000
```

would be reduced to "eight ones, followed by nine unstable bits, followed by
eight zeros".  In the cases where the number of unstable bits is zero or one, there would be no need to store the polarity of the next stable run [following zero unstable bits, it would be the opposite of the previous; following one it would be the same as the previous].

Answer (score 0):

A logic analyzer is one option, but you may run in to similar limitations on trace length and storage.  You will probably want to look at a more custom solution, say using an FPGA to spool the data into DRAM and/or transfer it to an SSD or perhaps even an SD card.  If the data stream is actually some form of serial data, then I would recommend an FPGA based approach where you can do clock/data recovery in the FPGA so you only need to store 1 bit per data bit and possibly implement some sort of streaming compression, then dump the data out into some sort of mass storage solution, either a large SSD via SATA or perhaps to a computer via USB, Ethernet, or PCIe.  You may also be able to get away with transferring uncompressed data (20 Mbps is not that bad when compared with USB 2 at 480 Mbps or Gigabit ethernet) and then compressing it with whatever host-side software you use to store the data.  This would enable using a much more complex compression algorithm that will result in a better compression ratio.

Comment: Note that the question wasn't about storing it all, but rather about compressing it.  Also, the question talks about the size of *disk* storage being an issue, so DRAM will probably be cost prohibitive.  Of course it is possible the question erroneously mentioned disk space when what it actually meant was disk bandwidth.

Comment: SD cards are one of the slowest types of modern storage you could choose.  Speed with flash storage comes in part from dividing across multiple dies, and SD cards are space constrained.

Comment: SD cards can run at several MBps.  If you can do CDR so you only need to store 1 bit per data bit, then you would only need 2.5 MBps.  SD cards can run anywherebetween 6 and 30 MBps.  So just one of those should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late, but it's been bumped.

Are you sure that working harder is the answer?  I would suggest smarter is a better approach.  There is a huge and fundamental difference between data and information.  Information is born of data.  Pure data is fairly useless without analysis.  Do you really need to store gigabytes of data?  What is it that you're looking for in the bit stream that you can't identify in 2 million bits (0.1s worth)?  There are statistical methods for inferring information from sampling a larger population.  You don't need to keep the population if you have the descriptive statistics.

You haven't told us what you're looking for, but I would suggest that it's likely you don't need so much permanent storage. And this then has a direct influence on the capture system.

Answer (score -2):

There exist many commercial solutions starting at $10k and way up for military and flight data recorders. AXIS, AMPEX etc.

To roll your own, consider a streaming [SERDES](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SerDes) to SIPO to FIFO to an i7 Linux box with a few 2TB drives with open source drivers. If this is beyond your budget or capacity, it is not possible.

### Added

Your request is unreasonable and not how to measure Bit Error rate, BER.
If you wish to record signal integrity for a long time, ie. BER or timing margin or eye pattern or window margin, then may I suggest a more sensible approach.

1) design your ideal clock and data separator from "bitstream"
2) define your BER vs SNR vs data patterns or equivalent.

3) Compare clock and data input with Rx output for jitter, margin, offset, drift, asymmetric, ISI etc with different data patterns

4) Choose method to inject different noise types.

5) e.g after injecting noise design message error rate counter e.g. 1 error in 10^x bits 
   - eg, 1k payload for BER= 10e-3 
   -  adjust noise level measure SNR then repeat every decade to 10e-7 ( 1 error per second) 
   - continue to 1e-9 ( 1 error per 100s) .

Then plot this and note all shifts in in the straight lines or breakpoints for different data patterns.

6) ANALYZE DATA

- Some of these breakpoint and slope constants relate to SNR, asymmetry or offset in comparator, pattern dependent ISI , group delay distortion in filters, random noise, PLL clock jitter and BW, phase error etc.  and more.

### personal experience

This was routine when I did this 30 yrs ago in the early 80's for T1 designs and later 10Mb/s bit stream for early 5.25" data from HDD's with soft error rates < 10e-9 and hard error rates < 10e-12 and we had many ways to measure this.

One machine had 2ns increment reducing clock recovery windows to detect data bit errors and +/- "window margin".

But simplest was 2 LC tapped delay lines with pseudo random sequence data selector for early normal late data with various ns increments.

- e.g. 10% of 100ns =10ns. This was injected digitally between comparator output and SERDES clock and data recovery in order to accelerate BER rate by reducing window margin or adding jitter.

Now there are fancier solutions but recording GB's/s of raw signal is not the best way to analyze a system design! unless you have some other unspecified real purpose.... then read 1st answer